# Get Result of System.Threading.Tasks.Task (ApplicationUser MVC)

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I just want to get my ApplicationUser in MVC. I'm trying this code:

```
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ApplicationUser> GetApplicationUser()
    {
        return await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User); 
    }

    var user = GetApplicationUser(); 
    var user2 = user.Result;
```

However, when I try to access user.Result I get exception

```
"One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)"
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Not sure how to access the result.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you controller action is aync Task, like so:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {            
        ApplicationUser user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        if (user != null) {
            // do more stuff here
        }
        // do more stuff here
        return View();             
    }

    private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync()
    {
        return _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted (without any exception details), I would *guess* that the problem is that `_userManager` is `null`.

However, you'll run into another problem if you fix that. Specifically, you should be using `await` instead of `Result`; [the latter can cause deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: userManager is not null, and I gave exception details I got. How do I use await instead of .Result? I tried var user = await GetApplicationUser();  but get error that it's not async even though it is. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaySmith: You should post the stack trace of the exception - that will tell you at least *where* it's happening. The error message you get regarding `async` is because the *calling* method is not async. Put another way, to use `await` you have to be within an `async` method, so you'll need to change that method to be `async` as well.

Answer (score -2):

I had to call the .Wait() function manually, and then I can access the .Result successfully. In addition, my HttpContext was null so I had to use it inside of Index() like

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        DoSomethingWith(HttpContext);
        return View();
    }
```

and

```
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ApplicationUser> user = GetApplicationUser(context); 
            user.Wait(); 
            var user2 = user.Result;
```

Comment: Not a pretty solution. Have you tried instead suggested public async Task<IActionResult> Index()